# How to perform groupby in one column and count distinct values of another column in each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as show below, which has only four columns.

[image]

I want to count the number of parts in 'Line_type' column in each work order group and divide the work_duration by the count of parts and fill a new column named 'part_work_hours' by the resultant of the division only where line_type==parts.

Output data frame is shown below.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected outcome if the `Work_Duration` differs between several row wih the same `Work_Order_Number` and `Line_Type=='parts'`? I.e. what would the expected output look like if the fourth 5 was a 6 instead.

Comment: @DavidWierichs  There is no such row in the data. Work duration is the total number of hours taken by an employee to replace the number of parts in each work order number.

Comment: So there are always these duplicates of rows? Are they needed, then? What I was after with the previous question is whether the part_work_hours are the mean of all work_durations divided by the count of the respective work_order_number or whether it only takes the work_duration from the corresponding line and divides that one.

Comment: @DavidWierichs, sorry for the confusion. It was my mistake.  there are more columns (around 70) in this dataset and values in other columns for the rows are different. So, essentially they are not the duplicated rows.  Let me phrase this question again for clarity.

Comment: Ah, okay, perfect, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @DavidWierichs, pictures modified for the clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215863/discussion-between-vaibhav-pandey-and-david-wierichs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the conditions were extracted, they were grouped and tabulated.

```
df['part_work_hour'] = df[df['Line_Type'] == 'parts'].groupby(['Work_Order_Number', 'Line_Type'])['Work_Duration'].transform(lambda x: x.mean() / x.count())
```